# Как узнать цифру 1 из адреса?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, в адресной строке браузера текст вида `http://localhost/pay/1`. Как можно через JQuery получить 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
location.href.split( "/" ).reverse()[0];
```

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "http://test.ru/12/34/56".split( "/" ).reverse()[0];
```